# why can't get all data from link from Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Why can't get all data from all links in Selenium

```
public class Selenium {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseUrl = "https://vnexpress.net/";
        String actualTitle = "";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        WebElement li;
        for(WebElement link:allLinks){
            String laylink = link.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(laylink);
            driver.get(laylink);
            li=driver.findElement(By.id("title_news_detail mb10"));
            System.out.println(li.getText());          

            driver.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work only for the first element as you are navigating away from the page where you have all the links and closing the driver, right after navigating to the link url.

Here is the logic that should work:

```
public class Selenium {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
        String baseUrl = "https://vnexpress.net/";
        String actualTitle = "";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        // wait for the links to display
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("a")));
        // get the number of links
        int numberOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size();
        WebElement li;
        WebElement currentLink;
        // iterate through the links
        String linksPage = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        for (int lnkNumber=0; lnkNumber>numberOfLinks; lnkNumber++) {
            currentLink = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(lnkNumber);
            // get the href
            String laylink = currentLink.getAttribute("href");
            // print the href
            System.out.println(laylink);
            // navigate to laylink
            driver.get(laylink);
            // find li element and print the text
            li=driver.findElement(By.id("title_news_detail mb10"));
            System.out.println(li.getText());
            // navigate to links page
            driver.get(linksPage);
            // wait for the links to display
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("a")));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When I run program have error. I until can't get all data web

Comment: Which line is throwing the error and what's the error message?

Comment: Message error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: a (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
 at selenium.Selenium.main(Selenium.java:33)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"a"}